# Using Session.Flush then ITransaction.Commit makes data rollback

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I'm trying to update an entity using `Session.Update` then continue to execute another SQL query. The other query did not see the changed value. When i traced it using profiler, `Session.Update` did nothing.

```
public class InvoiceService()
{
    public void Update(Invoice invoice)
    {
        using (var trans = BeginTransaction())
        {
            Session.Update(invoice); //Nhibernate did not update invoice. 

            ExecuteNamedQuery(); //Query executed before invoice updated.

            trans.Commit(); //Invoice updated.
        }
    }
}
```

Then i add Session.Flush after Session.Update.

```
using (var trans = BeginTransaction())
{
    Session.Update(invoice);
    Session.Flush()

    ExecuteNamedQuery();

    trans.Commit();
}
```

After `Session.Flush` executed, SQL query for update is executed also. 
It works perfectly. The execution order is correct. But then i executed another method to get all invoices. Committing transaction makes nhibernate execute update query to update my updated invoice earlier with old values. (ex: Quantity = 20, updated to 10, then updated again to 20)

```
public void FindAll()
{
    using (var trans = BeginTransaction())
    {
        var invoices = Session.CreateCriteria<Invoice>().List<Invoice>();

        trans.Commit(); // In here invoice that i updated earlier get updated again, using old values.

        return invoices;
    }
}
```

**Why it's getting updated again?**

**What's the solution for this problem?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Update` is an unfortunate name for the method; the purpose of `Update` is to attach a transient instance to a new session. See the [documentation for update](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating) and make sure you understand [instance states](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-states).

The invoice is updated to the original values because NHibernate thinks it has changed. This "phantom" update may be caused by a property changing unexpectedly. A typical root cause is a nullable database column mapped to a non-nullable property (or vice-versa). The easiest way to troubleshoot is to turn on `dynamic-update` in the session factory configuration so that you can see which properties NHibernate detects as dirty.